# Adding values in Set datatype from jsp in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Set datatype in my model and I have to add value into it from jsp.

below is my model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student extends UrlEntity {

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_SUBJECT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID") })
private Set<Subject> subjects;

}
```

I have to get values from the user and fill it in this collection and I am using something like this:-

```
<strong>Qualifying Papers:</strong>

<c:forEach var="subject" items="${subjects}" varStatus="status">

<form:select type="text" class="form-control"
path="subject[${status.index}]" id="subjects"
placeholder="Select Qualifying Paper" required="required">

<option disabled selected></option>
<c:forEach var="qualifyingSubject"
items="${qualifyingSubjects}">
<option value="${qualifyingSubject.paperNumber}">${qualifyingSubject.paperName}</option>
</c:forEach>

</form:select>
```

The error I am getting while adding object in the list is :-

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type in.jmi.model.Subject for property subjects[0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value

I am familiar with `form:input` and using path variable with it, I want to know how to use it for `Set`
I have seen many of the SO answers but unable to figure out how to use them in my case.
For example,I have got the above code for jsp from SO, but it is not displaying input box (maybe because varStatus="status" is 0, since my Set has zero values in it).

In Short I have to add values in HashSet from jsp.

Comment: Is there any specific usage for `Set` type except `unique` values?

Comment: Not really .! and after lot of research I am thinking about using list ..if you have any idea how to do this with list, Please share.

Comment: Have you checked this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/)?, implemented with map. And one more [post](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-populate-and-validate-dropdown-example/) with list.

Comment: @VinothKrishnan Basically what I am trying to accomplish here is I have a list of subjects which I am displaying from the dropdown(done) and when the user select a subject, the object is added to the list..(second part is pending) , I have gone through both articles not sure how to apply it here.! The error I am getting while adding object in the list is :-Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type in.jmi.model.Subject for property subjects[0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value

Comment: I'm not sure about your `second part`. Can you explain me a bit more? Is it a `multiselect`? If not, why you're trying to add it in the list?

Comment: @VinothKrishnan it is not a multiselect, I have this different category for subject and for every category there is a drop down, and `subjects` field add each subject object which the user selects from various drop downs, is it clear or should I explain more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107545/discussion-between-vinoth-krishnan-and-md-faisal).